# Wifi Direct in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct

How to implement wifi direct in react native? I need text communication using wifi direct. I tried with different libraries, but not able to find a proper solution. Please help.

Comment: Hi Saran, could you elaborate more about what you have done so far? E.g. with sample code or project?

Answer (score 1):

You Can try this package
using TCP

```
npm install react-native-tcp --save
```

Otherwise if you want wifi direct, you shoud write your code in java(for android)/objective c(for ios) then make inter communicate between react native and java..deponds on your correspond needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install react-native-wifi-direct
```

Here, is the link to the entire [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-direct)

This supports only Android though.